# Amazon S3 multipart upload: Can I upload a partial file to a part?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

That is, I am recording a time sensitive video, so I want to reduce upload latency as much as possible. What I want to do is, as I'm recording the video, I want to upload the recorded chunks while still recording.

So let's say I am recording a 10 min video. Instead of uploading the entire video at the end, I want to record, say, a minute, upload that as part of my multipart upload, while recording the next min. Once the recording is complete, I only need to upload the last min at the end and then call s3 multipart to complete the upload. This way, the latency between the end of the recording to when it's available in S3 is closer to the upload time of 1 min of video instead of the upload time for 10 min of video

Is this possible with S3 multipart uploads?

Comment: If your file format only grows, then yes, it's possible.  For some video formats that modify sections as they grow, then it's probably possible, though technically difficult.  That said, when I've seen something like this problem with live video streams, generally the solution is to create small segments, and upload them as they're done.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I also considered creating small videos and then uploading each one individually, but then it becomes more difficult on the UI side when I want to display a single seamless video, or if I want to perform operations on the video (eg, now I have to do a delete for each part instead of a single delete)